# Unable to find a version of 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

My current **asp.net mvc app** needs **11.0.2** version of 'Newtonsoft.Json'

However, I want to add a nuget package "UmbracoCMS" that needs **Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2 && < 11.0.0)'**

Please let me know how I could handle this in the **web.config**

I tried assemblyredirect but that didn't help. Thank you.

Comment: @Chad I'm trying to install the latest UmbracoCMS on an asp.net mvc application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to find a version of 'Newtonsoft.Json'

This issue is not related to assembly-redirect, so you could not resolve it by `web.config`. That is because the prerequisite for assembly-redirect is that different versions of the `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly should be all acceptable for your project and we use assembly-redirect to select one of the version to our project.

Check [a sample link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why).

However, your current question is that you can not get both versions to work for your project. Your `asp.net mvc app` needs **11.0.2** version of `Newtonsoft.Json`, but the nuget package `UmbracoCMS` that needs `Newtonsoft.Json` (**>= 10.0.2 && < 11.0.0**). You can not use both versions, so you can not use assembly-redirect to select one of the version to your project.

To resolve this issue, you have to resolve the reference conflict. Could you only use `Newtonsoft.Json` 11.0.2 for your asp.net mvc app? Can you use Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2/10.0.3 instead? If yes, you can install `Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2/10.0.3`, then you can install the nuget package `UmbracoCMS`. If not, I am afraid you could not install the nuget package `UmbracoCMS`.

Hope this helps.