# loading multiple.net assemblies with same AssemblyVersion from a plugin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linker, nuget

I'm in dll hell.

I'm building a plugin for a huge, ancient and very powerful software suite called ANSYS. They have a plugin framework. I had hoped that they would magically handle everything for me via `AssemblyContext`s or `AppDomain`s or some other clever dotnet device that I don't understand. They do not.

The result is that I've created an application that depends on GRPC.core 1.16.0 via nuget. I wrote a little application that drives my plugin with a winform host. It loads and works perfectly, finding my library in `~/myproject/bin/debug/grpc.core.1.1.16.dll` that exists right beside the class-library that is my plugin, no problem.

When I run my plugin in the ANSYS process space, which happens to also depend on grpc 1.0.0.0, the linker finds `C:\Program FIles\ANSYS\...\WIN64\grpc.core.dll`. No Good.

One odd thing about the Nuget GRPC package is that it adds a reference with a "reference version" of 1.0.0.0, where most other nuget packages have their reference version match the nuget package version. If i manually change the reference version the compiler wont find the library.

```
<Reference Include="Grpc.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Grpc.Core.1.16.1\lib\net45\Grpc.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

> edit: the key is in the above line. The Nuget published Grpc.core artifact is at `AssemblyInformationVersion=1.16.1.0, AssemblyFileVersion=1.16.1.0, AssemblyVersion=1.0.0.0`. I logged this as [a request against GRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/19024). More Below.

Thus I need to tell the runtime linking facilities not to use grpc.core...dll found in ANSYS's own binary directoryWhats more, there is exactly one dll (and its dependents) that I wish to load from my parent processes context: and that's ANSYS API dlls themselves, which are probably already in the GAC. In my project I've included this as a non-nuget reference with "build action: do not copy" selected.

So my questions:

1. <strike>is there something simple and easy I can do at runtime to tell the runtime-linker "when somebody loads a type from an assembly you think should be `grpc.core`, do not load 1.0.0.0, find 1.16.0.0 exactly"?</strike>

   > the runtime was already matching the needed library by "strong
   >   name". The problem is that the 1.16.0 is a misnomer. That version
   >   string was informational, but the assembly itself was version
   >   1.0.0.0. Fusion was loading the library I wanted by exact match already.
2. is there something smarter I can do with appdomains or contexts or another C# device to explictly enter some kind of nested scope? Could I go so far as to log this as a bug in ANSYS's API?

I've tried digging into this myself, but I'm not a dotnet expert and finding out whether I'm looking at a nuget package configuration option --which isn't relevant to me, or an old-fashioned dotnet runtime option, has been very tricky.

---

update 1:

I've tried using `AppDomain.CreateDomain`, and it does indeed solve my problem, but it also requires me to provide a marshalling strategy for the already-loaded API objects. In other words, if you're programming against a plugin framework that has an api similar to:

```
public void DoMyPluginsFunctionality(ApiProvidedInputContext context){

  var myPlugin = AppDomain.Create(
      strongName: "MyCompany.MyPlugin.; Version=1.2.3.4 ...",
      baseDirectory: "C:\\Program Files\\MyPlugin\\bin"
  )
  //success! MyCompany.MyPlugin loads the version of GRPC I want!

  myPlugin.unWrapAsDynamicProxy().doFunctionality(context)
  //error: No marshalling strategy and/or not serializable and/or swizzling errors
}
```

Then the runtime will require you to marshall (serialize) the `context` variable, because .net will not let you share memory across AppDomain boundaries.

So my new question:
- given I cant use AppDomains myself
- given that Grpc.core is always published as `AssemblyVersion=1.0.0.0`

What are my options?

- Stop using newer features of GRPC.core and live in fear of my parent processes dependencies
- use [a strategy similar to shading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297276/what-is-a-shaded-java-dependency). *Is there something like shading in the .net world*?
- Edit the published binary's version metadata. *Can I dynamically edit a published binaries version?*
- rebuild GRPC myself with the version string updated --effectively a private fork of GRPC.

---

update 2:

The GRPC build system seems like its quite large and well maintained, so I'm hoping I can simply build it and change a vcproj file to include an updated version string.

Unfortunately it also seems quite complex, and I haven't quite got the targeting/cross-compiling (x64 targeting x86) worked out.

Comment: This may help: [Assembly binding redirect: How and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why)

Comment: binding redirect won't help when the two files have the same assembly version. @Groostav what error do you actually get, you only said "no good". I just want to validate my assumption.

Comment: I get a `TypeLoadException: Could not load type ... grpc.Interceptor`, which was added [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/12613). Version redirection is all I'm looking for, though I suppose there is still wiggle-room if a use a library that doesn't use sane version-numbers. Is there no better solution to strictly enforce that I get exactly the DLLs I built with?

Comment: and I'm sorry for being so obtuse @JohnWu, but doesn't the `app.config` file only apply to the `exe` project type? The way we deploy our plugin is as a class library with some magic method names that are "discovered" by the plugin system.

Comment: Usually you'd configure the binding redirect for the entire application. This is what I would recommend. But it is also possible to create [.NET configuration for DLL files](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2010/09/05/configuration-settings-for-net-class-libraries-dlls/).

Comment: In hindsite the problem is that all versions of GRPC have an `AssemblyVersion` of 1.0.0.0, _though they have different `AssemblyFileVersion` and `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attributes_, used by things like NuGet, to suggest different versions. Fusion is not able to pickup on this. I've created [this issue with GRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/19024)