# C# Getting System.IO.FileNotFound Exeception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.security

I'm trying to create a program in C# that can manipulate the mouse cursor. I am getting a System.IO exception when I call the method in main and run the program.

I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2019. To run the method below, I am using `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`. I have both referenced.

```
 public static void AutomateMouse()
 {
       int x = 500;
       int y = 500;
       Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
       Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position.ToString());
 }
```

The expected result of this method was printing of the cursor to the coordinates specified in the method. I get this exception, on the fifth line when I run the program:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
 'System.Security.Permissions, 
Version=0.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Comment: I suggest cleaning and rebuilding your application, and also clear the bin and obj directions from the solution. Something is out of line here.

Comment: `Version=0.0.0.0` is definitely wrong - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Permissions/. If rebuild doesn't help, then it is either some [assembly binding redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why) issue. Or it is a case of mishmashed dependencies (.net framework, .net standard...) Can you show us contents of your csproj file (not all, only the framework and referenced libraries section for System.Drawing and Permissions)?

Comment: I have fixed the problem. I was using core instead of framework and there was some compatibility problem with System.Drawing. I switched to framework and now the program runs fine. Thanks.