# How to deal with System.InvalidOperationException: DataReader.GetFieldType(13)? (again)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqldbtype

After upgrading my ASP.NET webforms application to .NET 4.7.2 (and 4.8) and changing the underlying database server to SQL Server 2017, I started to get this exception:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: DataReader.GetFieldType(13) returned null.

Underlying datatype of column 13 in the dataset is `GEOGRAPHY`. I have researched a bit about possible causes and this are things I have tried without success.

1. The machine should have an instance of SQL Server installed. I have it. On my dev computer I have SQL Server 2017 Express and the “production” has SQL Server 2017 for the big boys. So, this is not the culprit.
2. There are suggestions to install package `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`. I have installed version 14.0.1016.290. The reference was created, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` was copied in the bin folder. This has not resolved the error.
3. Another suggestion was to put this call into the `Global.asax`:

   ```
   public class Global_asax : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ...
           /* For ASP.NET Web Applications, add the following line of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs: */
           SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
       }
   }
   ```
4. And as a last resort I have added assembly redirect in a `web.config`. I am not sure if I got publicKeyToken right.

   ```
   <assemblyBinding>
       ...
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" 
                             publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   ```

None of the above resolved my problem and this were all the suggestions I could find on various forums and stack exchange. I have looked into the source code of `GetFieldType()` method found at http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader@cs/1305376/SqlDataReader@cs but it offered no clue.

I have thought about there might be some old remnant from previous .Net version that calls incorrect version of this method, but I do not know how to check this. I just think it is a shame Microsoft cannot keep their stuff together. Old version of my app just simply worked.

IMPORTANT: To all of you who think this question was already answered: it was not! It is a persistent problem.

UPDATE - ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
My previous configuration on development computer and production server was .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008. After upgrading the database to SQL Server 2017 I changed only the connection strings on existing app and it worked. Actually it is still used in production since newer versions od .NET simply do not work.

After that I upgraded my dev machine to .NET 4.8, entity framework to 6.4 and compiled the app. And as result Geography datatype was broken. All steps I have take to remedy this are above.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code you use to test/replicate this error using data reader, as well as the corresponding result in SQL. So far I cannot replicate this error.

Comment: The problematic bit is DataReader.GetFieldType() method for columns using Geography data type. The problem is not the code, the problem is .Net Framework or compilation process.

Comment: In the title you say (again)… is this a reference to a past issue you have experienced? I have been using EF since it was released along with spatial types and have not encountered this particular issue so I think it is something deeper in your implementation, not just code references but the underlying design of your data classes. I'm happy to consult more offline if none of the advice in my solution helps.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller No. The problems around this exception appear oftenm yet no solution has been found until now. And as far as I could gather, it is a persistent issue for years now.

Comment: That's why I'm curious to see some code examples, I have been using EF religiously for years and have only come across errors remotely like this when the query result contains only null values for a geography column and the field is marked as required in the model.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I have created a simple prograsm to demonstrate the problem, You can take a look at it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487385/microsoft-sqlserver-types-assembly-causes-problems-with-geography-datatype-how
 I am quite certain it is not EF related problem per see but underlying System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: In your binding redirects I see you only mentioned specific version - 10.0.0.0 If the issue is still not resolved try specifying range of versions like `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"`. Refer to this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why

Comment: @GrayCat No binding redirect does not solve the issue. I have tried that. To reserach this I have created the minimu console app to demonstrate problem, See if you feel so inclined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487385/microsoft-sqlserver-types-assembly-causes-problems-with-geography-datatype-how

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you have tried will fix a different exception, usually variations of this:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found. '

If you are not seeing this error, then we can safely assume that a compatible version of *types* was found and this is usually enough to say that spatial queries will execute.

> **Data Type Recommendation**
>   I can't say that it is related to this for sure, but for greater success in EF with spatial types you should consider using `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` in your data classes (model), instead of `System.Spatial.Geography`
>
> > This will still resolve to *SQL* `Geography` data type.

To furthur investigate would require more information around the data model and the code that executed to raise the specific exception that OP has experienced. Without this information, I have taken an older *commercial* ASP.Net, OData v4 API project that was running:

- .Net 4.6.1
- Entity Framework 6.2.0
- Microsoft.Spatial 7.3.1
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76
- System.Spatial 5.8.3

I then upgraded the framework version and references for each project in the solution, there were a few NuGet packages to process so I used this command after changing the framework version of each project to 4.7.2:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies
```

Now the project is as follows:

- .Net 4.7.2
- Entity Framework 6.4.0
- Microsoft.Spatial 7.6.2
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.1016.290
- System.Spatial 5.8.4

The project still works as before, I can query a `Paddock` from my database and can see the geospatial fields in the result:

- ***NOTE:*** in this example the *Geospatial* fields are defined as follows:

  ```
  public DbGeography Perimeter { get; set; }
  public DbGeography GateLocation { get; set; }
  ```

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:1231/odata/$metadata#Paddocks(EntityID,FarmID,PropertyNumber,VicseedID,VicseedCode,PropertyArea,SketchFile,Isolated,Perimeter,GateLocation,State,SketchData,DefaultInspector)/$entity",
    "EntityID": 8242,
    "FarmID": 6065,
    "PropertyNumber": "1",
    "VicseedID": 3002,
    "Isolated": false,
    "Perimeter": {
        "Geography": {
            "CoordinateSystemId": 4326,
            "WellKnownText": "CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (146.68923684498316 -38.263219203427454, 146.67772453918761 -38.263219203427454, 146.67772382723493 -38.272258363952844, 146.68923755693584 -38.272258363952844, 146.68923684498316 -38.263219203427454))"
        }
    },
    "GateLocation": {
        "Geography": {
            "CoordinateSystemId": 4326,
            "WellKnownText": "POINT (146.68301582336429 -38.263961881396469)"
        }
    }
}
```

### What to check next?

Run the same SQL query directly in *SQL Management Studio*, record the results and publish into your question.

Then also publish the code that executes the same query but raises the captured exception.

---

After full regression testing, I can find no new anomolies in the API or the front end and from this I have the personal confidence to reccomend upgrading both to `.Net 4.7.2` and `Entity Framework 6.4`

Comment: After upgrade my configuration is similar to yours. .Net 4.8, Entity Framework 6.4.0 and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76. I am not using System Spatial because it is not relevant. I am willing to bet that in my EF fails for the same underlying issue as DataReader. So I am concentrating to resolve that.