# What purpose does <runtime> serve in app.config?

Tags: .net, app-config

I just updated some nuget packages for my Console application and now my app.config has this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This entire section was not there previously. I have other packages that are not listed here, only those that were updated are included.
It worked fine before and it worked fine now. What exactly is this section accomplishing and why is it not complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assembly Binding redirect: How and Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why)

Comment: Further reading [Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Answer (score 0):

If you have NuGet items that depend on other items, where you may have dependencies for multiple versions of the same thing, this is to help resolve those.