# Keeping nuget packages contained within a library

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, serilog

I have a .net framework application and a library that sets up Serilog. Here is the structure:

Edit:

[Code in github](https://github.com/q-bertsuit/SerilogTest)

[image]

program.cs

```
using Serilog;
using System;
using Library;
    
namespace SerilogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = Log.ForContext(typeof(Program));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggerInstaller.Install();

            Logger.Information("It works!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

LoggInstaller.cs

```
using Serilog;


namespace Library
{
    static public class LoggerInstaller
    {
        static public Serilog.Core.Logger Install()
        {
            //SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            string logFileName = "MyLog.log";

            var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                                .WriteTo.File(logFileName, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 50000)
                                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = config;

            return config;
        }

    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
        <add key="serilog:using:Console" value="Serilog.Sinks.Console" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:Console" />

        <add key="serilog:write-to:Console.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />

        <add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://localhost:5341" />

        <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />

        <add key="serilog:using:Thread" value="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithThreadId" />

        <add key="serilog:enrich:FromLogContext" />

        <add key="serilog:using:Environment" value="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithMachineName" />

        <add key="serilog:using:Process" value="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithProcessId" />

        <add key="serilog:using:Memory" value="Serilog.Enrichers.Memory" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithMemoryUsage" />

        <add key="serilog:using:AssemblyName" value="Serilog.Enrichers.AssemblyName" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithAssemblyName" />
        <add key="serilog:enrich:WithAssemblyVersion" />

        <add key="serilog:enrich:with-property:Application" value="SerilogTest" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I run this code I get the following exception in the library

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Serilog.Sinks.Console' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
> find the file specified.'

[image]

I have to include all the extra Serilog libraries in the SerilogTest app to get it to work. Why is this needed? Why is it not enough to have them in the library?

Comment: Try with the new csproj sdk-style.

Comment: I haven't heard about that before?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit Link to docs on the new csproj SDK style that vernou suggested - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

Comment: I'm on .net framework 4.7.2. I can't migrate .net core unfortunately

Comment: New sdk-style is compatible with .NET Framework, just it don't exist template. You need create .NET Standard project and edit the csproj to replace `netstandard2.0` by `net472`.

Comment: I tried creating a .net standard library, changing it to net472, and adding all the libraries. I'm still getting the same exception

Comment: `<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />` is in the .csproj file

Comment: Can you check if `Serilog.Sinks.Console` is in build result (in `bin` folder)?

Comment: would be more useful if you post proj file content, not image

Comment: add [bindredirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why) for `Serilog.Sinks.Console` on `app.config` file, did it help?

Comment: @Vernou It's only in the library bin folder, not the consoles bin folder

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I couldn't get it to work unfortunately

Comment: I put the code in guthub https://github.com/q-bertsuit/SerilogTest

Comment: @Q-bertsuit there's no point in uploading anything to GitHub. Post it *in the question itself*. The quickest solution would be to add the NuGet packages you want to your executable. Neither app.config nor binding redirects are going to load a non-existent dll. Besides, it's the *executable* that sets up logging, not the libraries. The libraries should only need to know about the core ILogger interface.

Comment: @Q-bertsuit as for `I can't migrate .net core unfortunately` you don't have much choice - .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. .NET Old is essentially legacy at this point, receiving only security updates. You'll have to upgrade sooner or later. You can already create WinForms, WPF and service applications in .NET 5

Comment: @Q-bertsuit what you called `LoggerInstaller` should be a single `ConfigureLogging` method in `Program.cs`, or a `Startup` class. It's no coincidence that .NET Core uses a Startup class to hold such methods

Comment: I am aware that I will have to upgrade to .Net Core eventually, but for several reasons I can't do it today, so I'm stuck with .Net framework.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If i put the code for LoggerInstaller in program.cs I will have code duplication inn all of my applications, that was the hole motivation for putting it in a library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess what you are saying is that what I am trying to do is not possible? I will have to include all 10+ serilog libraries and the code for setting it up inn all my applications?

Comment: That's a LOT easier to do with .NET Core. In .NET Old, indirect requirements have to be added explicilty. Otherwise you'd be able to add just `Serilog.Sinks.Console` and get `Serilog` as well. In .NET Old, you *have* to add indirect dependencies as well

Comment: Yet another argument for me to give my boss that we should prioritize moving to .Net Core soon :-)  For now I don't have much choice though..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ` indirect requirements have to be added explicilty` This means adding a package using nuget right?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit as for pulling all logging configuration to a single library, no application will have the *same* configuration. Maybe they'll need different log file names, different categories, or different sinks. Maybe you'll want to log errors and verbose messages to separate files. Maybe you want to add centralized logging, eg to a database, at some point. Add more sinks. At some point it will be easier to either configure in code, or put everything in the settings file

Comment: @Q-bertsuit why put `WriteTo.File` in code for example? Why not put even that in the settings file?

Comment: But I DO wan't everything in an app.config file! And that file we be different for many of the applications. I was just looking for a way not not have to duplicate the LoggerInstaller code and having so many extra nuget packages in every project.

Comment: @Because I wan't to construct the loggfiles path from code (in base folder of the solution )

Comment: If it was a fixed relative path I would have put it in app.config as well

Comment: Your requirements contradict each other, and the code you want to avoid duplicating 4 lines. As for the file path, that's one of the reasons creating a single log configuration is hard. Each application will have different requirements

Comment: As for not having so many extra packages, that's the main difference between .NET Core and .NET Old. In .NET Old, to get the same behavior you'd have to create your own NuGet package that adds all other dependencies and the logging configuration.  This means creating a NuSpec file to the library that explicitly references the other packages and add the generated NuGet to your executable, not the project reference

Comment: Why can't you move to .NET Core for a new application? You can even package the entire solution into a single executable, so a missing runtime is no concern

Comment: Just to be clear, I completely agree that a single log configuration is hard. That has never been the point. It's actually quite a bit more than 4 lines of code, I've left out code for simplicity.

Comment: I'm not creating a new application, I'm replacing log4net with Serilog and Seq in a solution with hundreds of existing projects. All .Net framework

Comment: If the answer is that you can't put the configuration in a separate settings file per application, and then put the setup code and all required packages in a separate library, than I'm happy with that answer. I was just looking for a why to not have to include the packages so many times all over the solution. But looks like there is no way around that. Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it