# Build error coming due to dll version conflict

Tags: c#, .net, build-error

I am getting the below in the output window when building the dotnet project.

*No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" and "Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx. Choosing "Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" arbitrarily.*

**Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common** only two projects in my solution contain this dll file referenced in them and only for Version=5.0.414.0.I am not sure why the above conflict is coming in the output window. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this conflict.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Target Framework for all the projects is NetFramework 4.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - at the moment we have no idea what other dependencies you might have. (I'd also strongly advise updating both VS and your target framework - the lowest supported version of .NET Framework that's currently supported by MS is 4.6.2.)

Comment: Probably some other packages you referenced might be internally depending on the same library but different version. You can add a [binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why) and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assembly Binding redirect: How and Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why)

Comment: @MatJ the Public token key is different so I don't think Assembly Binding redirect will work.

Comment: Have you tried remaking a new project and then copying the code over to it? it's Probabbly a messed up project.