# What is the cause of error 0x80131040 when creating Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I tried uninstalling the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` nuget package and reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Comment: Try binding redirects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/

Comment: How did this error come about? Is this an action in Visual Studio, or by running some code, or by running a command?