Confused on Binding Redirect old version range
Previously in my project, I have below binding redirect
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyPackage" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>

Now, I am upgrading 'MyPackage' to version '5.0.0.0' in the package file and change the binding redirect as below.
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyPackage" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>

When I start my service, it throws below error

Could not load file or assembly 'MyPackage, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

However, if I have below binding redirect, everything works.
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyPackage" publicKeyToken="" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>

Why this is happening? Why oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" did not work?

To redirect one assembly version to another, use the  element. The oldVersion attribute can specify a single assembly version or a range of versions. The newVersion attribute should specify a single version. For example,  specifies that the runtime should use version 2.0.0.0 instead of the assembly versions between 1.1.0.0 and 1.2.0.0. Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

This might be helpful as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why
