How to configure strongly named driver version?
I have an ASP.NET Core application (.NET 8) that is using the MongoDB C# driver.
The application is using an older component that seems to require MongoDb 2.4.4. Till now, this was not a problem, even with MongoDb C# driver 2.27.0.
But now, the latest version of MongoDB C# driver 2.28.0 has a potential breaking change. Since I updated to this version, my application does not compile anymore (because of the old component).
The MongoDB Team suggests to use something like this:


<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver"
                                  publicKeyToken="94992a530f44e321"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.28.0.0"
                                 newVersion="<version number to use>" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Bson"
                                  publicKeyToken="94992a530f44e321"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.28.0.0"
                                 newVersion="<version number to use>" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver.Core"
                                  publicKeyToken="94992a530f44e321"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.28.0.0"
                                 newVersion="<version number to use>" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>



I adapted the snippet to my needs:


<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.4.4" newVersion="2.28.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>



I have no idea where to add or insert the snippet though.
My first thought was *.csproj. But when I add the snippet at the root level, Visual Studio says "XML document cannot contain multiple root level elements". And when I insert the snippet inside the <Project> tags, the compiler claims "The element <configuration> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.
I am kind of lost now and happy for any help!

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why

@dododo: Thank you. The link you posted suggests to put the snippet in the app.config. Since I am working with an ASP.NET application this would rather be web.config in my case. So, I just created a web.config manually in my app's root folder and pasted the snippet. However, this did not impresss the C# compiler too much. Still error messages all over the place that ask me to add a reference to MongoDB.Driver Version 2.4.4.0.

all I can is to provide you another example https://github.com/CloudBreadProject/CloudBread/blob/ea0b72014754709524ea2a74c152ae91ddcc72bf/web.config#L96
